# Cypher Where Clause NOT working

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using the below Cypher I am trying to get all Zones that are not deleted and their items. The issue here is that the where clause doesn't seem to work at all. It still returns all zones, although some of them are deleted. Any idea what I am missing?

```
Match(n:Zone)
WITH n
WHERE NOT n.deleted in [NULL, 'false'] 
OPTIONAL Match(n)-[]-(items:Item) 
RETURN n, items;
```

Using version 2.3.1

Comment: What is the value of the deleted property of the nodes that are being returned and that you expect to not be there? 'false' and false are two different values. Also, are you sure you want 'deleted' Zones to stay in the graph?

Comment: there are two zones. One is set to null the other one is set to true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you cannot deal with nulls with the `IN` predicate.  I think you need to re-craft this with `(n.deleted = false or n.deleted is null)`. Also, re-ordering the `WITH` would limit the number of zones you return from the database.

```
MATCH (n:Zone)
WHERE NOT coalesce(n.deleted, false) = false
WITH n
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)--(items:Item) 
RETURN n, items;
```

Comment: @SonuKapoor So, you actually **do** want `Zone`s that are deleted? If so, can you correct your question? This query returns `Zone`s that have `deleted = true`.

Comment: Note you can also use `coalesce()` to provide a default for a value in case it's null! `WHERE NOT coalesce(n.deleted, false) = false`